# HTML li value start with 0 in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

While writing an HTML code, I've entered value of li as '01' like :

```
<ul>
  <li value="01">Jan</li>
  <li value="02">Feb</li>
</ul>
```

This is working in all browser except IE. In IE 10/11 li values are changed "01" to "1" and codes generated as :

```
  <ul>
   <li value="1">Jan</li>
   <li value="2">Feb</li>
  </ul>
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? I want the value remain as "01" in all browser.

Here is the full code :

```
       <ul>
            <li value="">All</li>
            <li value="01">January</li>
            <li value="02">February</li>
            <li value="03">March</li>
            <li value="04">April</li>
            <li value="05">May</li>
            <li value="06">June</li>
            <li value="07">July</li>
            <li value="08">August</li>
            <li value="09">September</li>
            <li value="10">October</li>
            <li value="11">November</li>
            <li value="12">December</li>
        </ul>
```

And here is the generated HTML code in IE :

[image]

Comment: Could you share your full source code? We can provide better answer, as we will know where the problem is

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem. I use 'data-value' attribute instead of 'value' attribute in LI tag. Now I can get the value correctly.

Comment: is there anything else that can be done? something from IE end.